# Execel IF(AND) function too many arguments

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

I am trying to format a cell (**B17**) based on the value of **B13**, it needs to be green if the following is true and red if false:

```
F17-E17-D17<=b13<=F17
```

I understand putting in two conditional formats to cover red and green but i cant get my formula to work. I have got it to:

```
=IF(AND($F$17-$E$17-$D$17)<=$B$13,$B$13<=$F$17,TRUE,FALSE))
```

this does not seem to work as it says there are too many arguments. Any help would be greatly recieved.

Answer (score 2):

This formula is wrong for a number of reasons.
Firstly, you have non-matching parenthesis.

Secondly, that is not how AND works. AND requires logical inputs (true/false), not numerical inputs. Arguments need to be separated by semicolons (;), in some cases by commas (,). Make sure you check what your excel requires in the tooltip as you type the function arguments. For more information see: [AND fuction documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9).

And lastly - IF is not required here at all. AND alone is sufficient. IF is a function required when you want to return custom output, other than TRUE or FALSE. (See: [IF function documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)) It's best to avoid it otherwise, if you want standard behaviour.

The proper function for your formatting would be:

```
=AND(($F$17-$E$17-$D$17)<=$B$13;$B$13<=$B$17)
```

I have used a semicolon (;) to separate arguments, but if your excel requires commas, change it to a comma (,).
This function returns a boolean TRUE or FALSE, which is exactly what you need for formatting rules.

Additional tip:
It's not neccessary to create two rules in this case. You can set the default cell background red, and set conditional formatting to change it to green when true.